# why null pointer exception appears in my application

Tags: java, android

i need a help, when i'm reading the JSON file in my application every thing is okay except when i'm read the cover source it always cause a null pointer exception however i'm including in my that when the value = null , then put the default cover but it always cause a null pointer exception this is the most important piece from the code

```
    just try            
String coverSource=jsonObjectInData.optJSONObject("cover").optString("source");
                if(coverSource.equals(null))
                {
                     page.setCoverSource("http://t1.gstatic.com/images? q=tbn:ANd9GcTnU1vitqZ3aQxGHLzsP3Xr5Yn4wI_2w1f2sihW2S1ZFaUko3YvrQ");

                }
                else
                {
                    page.setCoverSource(coverSource);

                }
```

Comment: If you're using an IDE, then it should issue a warning like, "*Object equals "null" is never true*".

Answer (score 2):

You need to check for null like this:

`if(coverSource == null)`

As `.equals` is a method called on an object. You need to check to see if that object exists before performing any actions on it.